# safe_concat error while using table_builder rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototypejs

I am using table_builder plugin and I am getting the following error

**undefined method `safe_concat' for ActionView::Base:0x00000100a81ef0**

What is safe_concat method and Can someone please tell me what am I doing incorrectly

**View Code**

```
<div id="event">
    <% calendar_for @events do |calendar|%>
        <%= calendar.head('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun') %>
        <% calendar.day do |date,articles|%>
            <%=h date.day%>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7. What I did was installing the plugin with cloning the project directly into vendor/plugins

git clone http://github.com/p8/table_builder.git

Then I checkout into a very specific commit (Before it was turned into a gem and made rails3 compatible)

git checkout -b pre-gem 21bb3fd2361b04076e7337603fcdd83b6428b47f

And everything was ok after that.

Important to note that if you have rails_xss plugin, it will try to escape html by default and print out a bunch of html tags on your page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the new version only works with Rails 3.

safe_contact seems to be a function only available to Rails.

I went to the table_builder site and followed the instructions to try and get it to work f with Rails 2.3.8, but to no avail.

Thankfully I had an older version of the plugin installed with a previous project and, after copying and pasting it to vendor/plugins, things now seem to work.

A bit annoying thought!

Not sure it helps ... but it is my two-penneth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with rails 2.3.11 and ruby 1.8.7 under Ubuntu Linux Platform. I solve my problem following this instructions:

1. Cloning the repo

   ```
   git clone http://github.com/p8/table_builder.git
   ```
2. Checking out into a very specific commit (compatible with rails 2.x)

   ```
   git checkout -b pre-gem 21bb3fd2361b04076e7337603fcdd83b6428b47f
   ```